# Clear PHP session on TAB/Window Close

Tags: php, session

Clear PHP session on TAB/Window Close

I would like to such as on tab / window close of e.g a website of mine, the php session will be clear.

I do use time() to expire a php non-active for 1800 seconds, but my site also require that if user close all tabs / window of my site, his php session will expire/not valid and require to auth again.

I use the following headers

```
<meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE">
```

BUt it doesnt' work too. I do use expires 0 meta header also and no-cache but same issue.

The session still work if I open a new tab and key in my website admin panel, as normally if I am not logged in, I key in the admin panel , it will redirect me to login page.

But because session still valid, this became a issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you wanna destroy it on a closed tab. But this should do the trick. ( it uses jQuery )

**Javascript / jQuery**

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "destroy.php"
     });
    }
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php how to destory your session